# issue with requirejs being called in switch satement

Tags: jquery, while-loop, switch-statement, requirejs

I am having an issue where I am reading a json object to build out a form. As I read the form field types I go through a switch statement on how to build the field with bootstraps. In some cases I want to call secondary libraries like datepicker.

```
for(var i=0, l=$custFormFields.length; i<l; i++) {
        $formLabel = $custFormFields[i].label;
        var $inputFieldType = '';
        var $inputEndTag = '';
        var $inputTagType = 'input';
        var $inputRequired = '';
        var $inputFieldWidth = '';
        var $inputFieldRows ='';
        var $inputMaxChar = '';
        var $inputdefaultValue ='';
        var $inputEnableSpellCheck ='';
        var $inputHidden ='';
        var $inputCanUploadAsset ='';
        var $textAreaDefaultVal = '';

        if ($custFormFields[i].required == "true") {
            $inputRequired = "required";
        } else {}        
switch ($custFormFields[i].fieldType){


                    case "dropdown":
                        fieldRendered = false;
                        var $optionLines ="";
                        $inputTagType = 'select';
                        $inputEndTag = "</select>";
                        for(var o=0, l=$custFormFields[i].tagOption.length; o<l; o++) {
                            var $optionInfo = $custFormFields[i].tagOption[o];
                            var $optionLines = $optionLines + '<option value="' + $optionInfo.value + '">' + $optionInfo.name + '</option>';
                        }

                        $formInput = '<' + $inputTagType + ' class="floatL" id="'+ $custFormFields[i].tagCode + '" name="'+ $custFormFields[i].tagCode + '" ' + $inputRequired + ' onchange="dropdownListener(' + $custFormFields[i].tagCode + ')" >' + $optionLines + $inputEndTag + '<label id="' + $custFormFields[i].tagCode + '_value"  class="control-label" />';
                        fieldRendered = true;
                    break
                    case "dropdown-editable":
                        fieldRendered = false;
                        var $optionLines ="";
                        $inputTagType = 'select';
                        $inputEndTag = "</select>";
                        for(var o=0, l=$custFormFields[i].tagOption.length; o<l; o++) {
                            var $optionInfo = $custFormFields[i].tagOption[o];
                            var $optionLines = $optionLines + '<option value="' + $optionInfo.value + '">' + $optionInfo.name + '</option>';
                        }

                        $formInput = '<' + $inputTagType + ' id="'+ $custFormFields[i].tagCode + '" name="'+ $custFormFields[i].tagCode + '" ' + $inputRequired + ' onchange="dropdownEditListener(' + $custFormFields[i].tagCode + ')" >' + $optionLines + $inputEndTag + '<input id="' + $custFormFields[i].tagCode + '" class="input-xlarge" type="text">'
                        fieldRendered = true;
                    break;
                    case "datePicker":
                        fieldRendered = false;
                        if (typeof Datepicker === 'undefined'){
                            require(['scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js'], function(data){
                                $formInput = '<div id="' + $custFormFields[i].tagCode + '_range" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc"><i class="icon-calendar icon-large"></i><span></span> <b class="caret" style="margin-top: 8px"></b>   </div><input type="hidden" id="'+ $custFormFields[i].tagCode + '" value="'+ $custFormFields[i].defaultValue + '"/>';

                            });
                            break;
                            fieldRendered = true;
                        }else {
                            $formInput = '<div id="' + $custFormFields[i].tagCode + '_range" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc"><i class="icon-calendar icon-large"></i><span></span> <b class="caret" style="margin-top: 8px"></b>   </div><input type="hidden" id="'+ $custFormFields[i].tagCode + '" value="'+ $custFormFields[i].defaultValue + '"/>';
                            break;
                            fieldRendered = true;
                        }
    var fri=0;
            while(fieldRendered == false){
               setTimeout(function() {}, 100);
               fri++
            }
            $formHTML = $formHTML + '<div class="control-group"><label class="control-label">' + $formLabel + '</label><div class="controls">' + $formInput + '</div></div>\n\r';
        }
        return $formHTML;
```

The problem I have is once I make my require call, the switch statement continues on and skips over the field using the previous passes info.

I even added in a Boolean that one start of the case is set to false and set to true once completed. Then do a while loop that should end once the Boolean is true. However the require call does not pull the script in, and I get stuck in an endless loop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Could it have *something* to do with the fact that the flag is set **after** the break statement?

```
require(['scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js'], function (data) {
    $formInput = '(snip)';
});
break;
fieldRendered = true; // <- dead code
```

---

Generally, some other parts look a bit dodgy to me, for example looks like you're trying to do a *busy spin* to wait for something here:

```
while(fieldRendered == false){
    setTimeout(function() {}, 100);
    fri++
}
```

Due to asynchronous nature of JavaScript this doesn't behave as you might expect it to; `setTimeout` schedules execution of an empty function 100ms from now and immediately proceeds to the next loop iteration, it doesn't wait 100ms before going to the next tick of the `while` loop.

The callback of the `require` won't execute as you'd expect it too, either; it will only run once `bootstrap-datepicker.js` is downloaded and initialised, which could be *long* after the entire function returns `$formHTML`.